# MapState updateTtlOnReadAndWrite based on keys or values?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

With a MapState and TTL config set to `updateTtlOnReadAndWrite()`, is the TTL updated when a key is read (e.g. calling `map.keys()`) or only when the value associated is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `updateTtlOnReadAndWrite()` is called, api like `contains()` will update the TTL of the associated value, even though we do not touch the value. For api `keys()`, the TTL will be updated when the iterator accesses those keys. TTL of values for keys not being touched by the iterator won't be updated.